# What does this vector array code do? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Having difficulty finding an explanation to this.

What does this code do? I understand it creates an array of vector but that's about it. 
How can I print the vector array and access elements to experiment with it?

```
 #define MAXN 300009
 vector<int>dv[MAXN];
 int main()
 {
  for(int i=1;i<MAXN;i++)
    for(int j=i;j<MAXN;j+=i)
        dv[j].push_back(i);
 }
```

Comment: By indexing into the raw array, and using the vector API on the referenced element.

Comment: What exactly puzzles you? It's a very basic program. If you currently learn c++ go on learning  you will understand soon.

Comment: Refer to this detailed documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/511/stdvector#t=201612070849558162046

Comment: I keep getting an 'out of range memory location' error. That is what puzzles me @Matthias

Comment: @borb183 with *just* this code? [Cannot reproduce that out of range error](http://ideone.com/kqqq2l). All subscripts in this code are in range. Whatever error you're getting, it isn't in this code.

Comment: Read a C++ tutorial. Seriously, this is very very basic code, and if you don't know how to print a vector, you haven't went through any tutorial yet. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-tutorial.html

Comment: @Aziuth Well, if you had the time to write this I'd safely assume you could have easily helped too. At present your comment helps no one

Comment: @borb183 The comment helped you. It gave you a link you should really read. Again, this is **basic** code, not something you should have any problems with if you worked through any tutorial. If someone explains to you such simple code, you will have learned nothing and when the next code comes, you won't understand it again. Do you see the downvotes people gave your question? That's why.

Comment: @Aziuth 1) You can't TELL someone to not have a doubt. 2) I've gone through that link already, and read the vector part. It said nothing about array of vectors. 3) You must stop deciding for others what they understand or will not in the future. 4) Your comment still helps no one. WhozCraig's answer Does. Explains the difference between your rank and his.

Comment: @Aziuth I recently re-picked C++ after changing streams. Came across an issue and asked. I suggest you to stop sweating about it..like really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is easy enough to instrument. The reality of what it ends up producing is a very simple (and **very** inefficient) [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Understanding that algorithm, you'll see what this code does to produce that ilk.

Edit: It is also a factor-table generator. See Edit below.

Instrumenting the code and dumping output afterward, and reducing the number of loops for simplification we have something like the following code. We use [range-based-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loops for enumerating over each vector in the array of vectors:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define MAXN 20
std::vector<int>dv[MAXN];

int main()
{
    for(int i=1;i<MAXN;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<MAXN;j+=i)
            dv[j].push_back(i);
    }

    for (auto const& v : dv)
    {
        for (auto x : v)
            std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
1 
1 2 
1 3 
1 2 4 
1 5 
1 2 3 6 
1 7 
1 2 4 8 
1 3 9 
1 2 5 10 
1 11 
1 2 3 4 6 12 
1 13 
1 2 7 14 
1 3 5 15 
1 2 4 8 16 
1 17 
1 2 3 6 9 18 
1 19
```

Now, note each vector that only has **two** elements (1 and an additional number). That second number is **prime**. In our test case those two-element vectors are:

```
1 2 
1 3 
1 5 
1 7 
1 11 
1 13 
1 17 
1 19
```

In short, this is a very simple, and incredibly inefficient way of finding prime numbers. A slight change to the output loops to only output the second element of all vectors of length-two-only will therefore generate all the primes lower than `MAXN`. Therefore, using:

```
for (auto const& v : dv)
{
    if (v.size() == 2)
        std::cout << v[1] << '\n';
}
```

We will get all primes from `[2...MAXN)`

---

**Edit: Factor Table Generation**

If it wasn't obvious, each vector has an ending element (that not-coincidentally also lines up with the subscripts of the outer array). All preceding elements make up the positive factors of that number. For example:

```
1 2 5 10
```

is the `dv[10]` vector, and tells you `10` has factors `1,2,5,10`. Likewise,

```
1 2 3 6 9 18
```

is the `dv[18]` vector, and tells you `18` has factors `1,2,3,6,9,18`.

In short, if someone wanted to know all the factors of some number `N` that is < `MAXN`, this would be a way of putting all that info into tabular form.

Comment: Thank you! This was a little part of a larger competitive coding solution that I was attempting to understand. I believe it is used for something other than prime number generation. Now I can understand it

Comment: @borb183 they're probably using it for a factor table, which it also generates. Adding that to the answer now. Glad you understand it.